# Unicode string through UDP socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I want to send and receive data (unicode utf-8 strings through udp sockets, `DatagramSocket`. I have been looking into SO for answers, but could only find solutions for TCP transfer using `InputStream` and like.

Is there a similar way for UDP?

**UDP Client**

```
package testsocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class TestSocketSender {

    private DatagramSocket sock;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSocketSender();
    }

    public TestSocketSender(){
        try {
            sock = new DatagramSocket();//, Inet4Address.getLocalHost());
            sendData("Hello World\u00A9");
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendData(String data) throws IOException{
        DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes("utf-8"), data.length(), InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 5060);
        sock.send(datagram);
    }
}
```

**UDP Server**

```
package testsocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class TestSocketListerner {

    private DatagramSocket sock;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSocketListerner();
    }

    public TestSocketListerner(){
        try {
            sock = new DatagramSocket(5060);//, Inet4Address.getLocalHost());
            while(true){
                System.out.println(recvData());
            }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String recvData() throws IOException{
        byte[] data = new byte[100];
        DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(data , data.length);
        sock.receive(datagram);
        return new String(datagram.getData(),datagram.getOffset(),datagram.getLength(),"utf-8");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a datagram-based protocol. It means that you can only send a fixed amount of data without any warranties about the data being delivered. The packet may be lost, the data inside may be corrupted because even the CRC is not mandatory in UDP and even worse - the packets you send may be reordered on the receiving side because of the multiple routers along the packet's way.

To implement something which looks like a Stream using the UDP channel is not trivial, but surely possible. You have to split the data into small portions (the MTU of the system), pack them with some recovery information, assign sequence numbers to each packet and provide some mechanism to reask packets which are lost on the way.

Answer (score -1):

send the length first.

Have your sender pack the bytes first, then send the length and then the string. I suggest you pack it into four bytes.

Have your reader, read 4 bytes, then reconstruct the length, then read the string.

You can then handle the problems of data not arriving and timing out, etc...